# Displaying distance scale ratio in google maps by using CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way that I could display the distance scale - in KM or Miles or anything reasonable - as it is shown in http://maps.google.com  when using the [CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library](https://github.com/BIOSTALL/CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library) ?

---

**Edited**

This is what I have done :

```
    $this->load->library('googlemaps');

    $config['center'] = $center['latitude'].' '.$center['longitude'];
    $config['zoom']    = '5';
    $config['cluster'] = false;
    $config['disableScaleControl'] = false;
    $config['scaleControlPosition'] = 'TOP_RIGHT';
    $config['disableDefaultUI']=false;

    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
```

And this is what I am getting :
[image]

Comment: I don't know the CodeIgniter Library, but this looks like a bug...

Answer (score 0):

The `mapOptions` object has a `scaleControl` property that is set to false by default. Please see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions).

Comment: I have looked into the Google's documentation. It uses javascript. I am looking to do it through php, using the Codeigniter Google-Maps Library.

Comment: Seems that the Codeigniter doc shows the same options. Did you have a look at `$disableScaleControl` and `$scaleControlPosition`?

Comment: I have tried it without luck. I was expecting to display the scale.

Comment: You didn't set `$disableDefaultUI` to true by any chance?